# WPF: Binding directly to a control

Tags: .net, wpf, binding

I need to bind a property of a `UserControl` directly to another control, rather than any specific property on that control. What's the best way to achieve this? I've tried various combinations of the `Binding` properties to no avail.

For some context, the `UserControl`has a `Next` property that specifies which control is next in the navigation hierarchy; it's similar to `TabIndex` but for context sensitive navigation.

```
<c:MyControl x:Name="First" Next="{Binding ???}" />
<c:MyControl x:Name="Second" />
```

From reading the docs, I assumed I should've been able to do: `{Binding Source=Second, BindsDirectlyToSource=True}`, but that didn't work.

Comment: What about binding to the parent, with `Path=Second`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [ElementName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.elementname.aspx) property is your [friend](http://richoncodedev.wordpress.com/2006/11/03/binding-properties/)

Comment: I tried `ElementName` before without any success, but after some further investigation it ends up it was working fine, but how I was debugging it was wrong. My overridden event was being called against `Second`, without me realising, so `Next` was always null. Once I realised this and got the event raising against `First`, the property was set.

Answer (score 3):

ArildF's answer **{Binding ElementName=Second}** is the best direct answer to your question, but have you considered using the WPF's built in navigation functionality?

```
<c:MyControl x:Name="First" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="1" />
<c:MyControl x:Name="Second" KeyboardNavigation.TabIndex="2" />
```

Also check out:

- KeyboardNavigationMode enum
- KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation / TabNavigation / ControlNavigation
- KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop
- Using <Grid> instead of <DockPanel> to keep controls in natural order

It may be that the functionality you desire is already covered by WPF.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Ray, and certainly for the example given it would be better to use what you've said; however, my example is an oversimplification of the design.